# A body tracking when adding a Azure Kinect

Tags: azure, azurekinect

I know that I can body tracking 5 people per Azure Kinect.
Is a total of 15 people tracking when connecting 3 Azure Kinect?

Comment: my understanding reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/system-requirements) is that with the minimum configuration allows you to track up to 5 people. Let me check if we have a benchmark to share though.

Answer (score 0):

There is technically no limit to the number of bodies the AKDK Body Tracking SDK can track. The number that can be tracked is gated by CPU (not GPU). There is no simple rule regarding how much CPU is required (same for GPU) as it is very much dependent on the customers' application.

I would encourage to test performance on various hardware configurations until you meet your project requeriments.